# Animation is Much Faster than the Duration Specified

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I was making animation in flutter. When I run it on emulator, the duration of the animation is correct, but when I run it on my device the animation is about 5x faster.

I found this when I looked it up -
[image]

But still the duration of the animation for users will be different depending on their developer settings.

So how do I fix this duration issue.

I am using version 3.3.10 btw.

Just attaching my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BookmarkAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  const BookmarkAnimation({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _BookmarkAnimationState createState() => _BookmarkAnimationState();
}

class _BookmarkAnimationState extends State<BookmarkAnimation>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation<double> _animation;
  bool _isBookmarked = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 7500),
    );
    _animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _isBookmarked = !_isBookmarked;
        });
        if (_animationController.isCompleted) {
          _animationController.reverse();
        } else {
          _animationController.forward();
        }
      },
      child: RotationTransition(
        turns: _animation,
        child: AnimatedCrossFade(
          firstChild: const Icon(
            Icons.bookmark_border,
          ),
          secondChild: const Icon(
            Icons.bookmark,
          ),
          crossFadeState: _isBookmarked
              ? CrossFadeState.showSecond
              : CrossFadeState.showFirst,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 7500),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I found out it has to do with some settings in the developer options. But the issue is that animation for users will be different depending on these settings.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, by default the animation speed is set to 1x in the Animation scale settings. If you want to make sure the animation speed is ok for all you may better to change your parameters. Or you may try this, find this file in the Android directory: AndroidManifest.xml and add this line:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).